# Maximal sum of products of two lists

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I need to write an algorithm based on dynamic programming approach and to be honest I got completely stuck.

Ok, so the problem is like that. I have two lists with the same (even) length. For example let's say that:

```
a = [43, 10, 40, 12]
b = [63, 73, 5,  13]
```

I need to use the dynamic programming approach to find maximal sum of products of paired numbers from those lists. The numbers can be only paired in such a way that:

`(a[n] * a[n+1]) V (b[n] * b[n+1]) V (a[n] * b[n])`

And obviously if you chose one of those combinations you can't use those numbers anymore.

What I actually need help with is finding the recursive function for that. And I really can't find it. Would be really grateful if someone could give me a hand with that.

Best regards

Comment: Can you show one example with the 2 lists you provide ? It is still quite unclear to an external reader.

Comment: From what I understand, the requirement is to find a set of pairs from the two lists, such that the numbers in the pairs are either adjacent in one of the list, or they are in the same position across the two lists, and we would like to maximize the sum of these products of pairs.
I guess in the example the answer would be {(63,73), (43,10), (40,12), (5,13)}

Comment: Imagine that the list elements are the ratings of episodes of two series A and B. The episodes are played in pairs every week. The episodes have to be shown in a consecutive  way. So the streamer wants to play shows in such a way to maximize "ratings". So if they decide to play A0, A1 in first week it will be 43 * 10, if A0,B0 it will be 63*43 etc. So they want to play the episodes in such combinations to maximize the final sum of ratings' products

Comment: So what is the "correct" answer for the data provided? `(63,73)`?

Comment: It is the 63*73 + 43*10 + 40*12 + 5*13

Answer (score 1):

The key insight here is that the matchings are coupled. If you match `a[i]` to `a[i+1]`, you also have to match `b[i]` to `b[i+1]`. Otherwise, there would be at least one unmatched entry. Therefore, as you walk through the list from left to right, you only have to decide whether to match vertically or horizontally.

To formulate this as a dynamic program, we propagate the function `S(i)` that records the maximum score that can be achieved using elements `0 .. i`. The recursive relation is then:

```
S(i) = max(
            S(i - 1) + a[i] * b[i],                        #vertical match
            S(i - 2) + a[i - 1] * a[i] + b[i - 1] * b[i])  #horizontal match
```

Of course, with appropriate boundary handling.

Comment: Hi, your answer helped me a lot however I'm still not sure what those boundary handlings would be? The only one i can think of is if i < = 0, return 0 (in Pythonic way of thinking) But this doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: If `i` is the first element, you don't have the option of matching horizontally. Further, you need to make sure that `S(i - 1)` or `S(i - 2)` exist. If they don't, use `0`.

Comment: So as I understand the code should be like that:

```def func(i):

    if i == 0:
        return a[i] * b[i]
    elif i > 0:
        return max(func(i - 1) + a[i] * b[i], func(i - 2) + a[i - 1] * a[i] + b[i - 1] * b[i])
    else:
        return 0
```